# He couldn't (or "can't"?) believe his eyes when he saw the results

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense

> He **couldn't** believe his eyes when he saw the results.
>
> He **can't** believe his eyes when he saw the results.

Should I use *can* or *could* in this sentence?
We usually say "I can't believe it.", can I say "I couldn't believe it."

Comment: The second sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it present or past **in this context?**

In your question, he *saw* the results, the matter is of past so...

> He ***could not*** believe his eyes when he saw the results

Comment: If it is present in this context. We have to use "can"?
He can not believe his eyes when he see the results.
Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, but it's *sees* (third person)

Comment: @MaulikV - it's trickier than that. It's either "He can not believe his eyes *now that he sees* the results" or "He would not be able to believe his eyes *when* he sees the results", IMHO.

Comment: @CopperKettle In a storytelling, it's possible. *He goes happily to the school thinking all good grades in the results. He sees the results but cannot believe his eyes!*